# Struggle with building simple doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm start to study linked list I think I got the idea very well however The implement is more difficult for me.
I do know that I do something wrong but I don't know what..
I think I don't use the pointer right.
I tried use the debugger but I didn't find the problem yet so I ask here for some help.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int id;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* pre;

}node;


void print_linked_list(node * a) {
int i = 0;
while (a) {
    printf("%3d\n", a->id);
    a = a->next;
}
}

node* get_linked_string() {
node* first;
node* current;
node* prev;

first = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
first->pre = NULL;

printf("Enter id: ");
scanf_s("%d", &first->id);

current = first; // save the first element 

prev = first; // save the previus 

// processing of the second and other items
while (first->id != 0) // current->id != 0
{
    current->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    current = current->next;
    printf("Enter id: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &first->id); // &current->id

    current->pre = prev; // save the previus 
    prev = current;  
}
current->next = NULL;


return first;
};
```

Thanks !!

** Ok I Struggled with is like a hour, but 1 min after I opened the post I founded the problem - somehow the is always happened.
I comments near the problems.

Comment: `typedef struct Node` -> `typedef struct node`. Read your warnings. There may be other issues though.

Comment: The chaining of your list is totally wrong. Take a piece of paper and a pencil and draw the elements of your list using arrows as pointers. Google _doubly linked list c_

Comment: The loop test in your printing function is dubious.  It should probably be `while (a != NULL)` or, if you prefer (I don't), `while (a)`.  You would not then need the printing after the loop and would be safe if passed an empty list.  The argument type should be `const node *` too; your printing code doesn't change the list it is given.

Comment: You don't immediately set `first->next` so if the ID entered is 0, your list is malformed. You should separate the I/O from the list management.  The semicolon after the close brace of the second function is an empty global declaration.  Don't put the semicolon there.  The scanf in the loop is reading into the wrong ID.